# How do I reference a second DB from an application cfc file

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, application.cfc

In our Portal application.cfc, we are defining (setting up) our DSN connections like so:

`<cfset this.datasource = "DSN1"> (Main DB)
<cfset this.datasource_1 = "DSN2">  (2nd DB)
<cfset this.datasource_2 = "DNS3"> (3rd DB)`

These are in the  tags. I have also moved then to the ‘OnApplicationStart’ function and cannot get it to work correctly.

This application.cfc if referenced in the main APP, that the other apps have access to (App2, etc…), my question is;

How do I reference the other datasources (this.datasource_2) in a query for the App2 application?

```
<cfquery name="queryname" datasource="**[What goes here]**"> For second datasource
```

The this.datasource DSN is always being referenced because there is no datasource listed in the cfquery tags.

Any help you can provide or links to send my way will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are DSN1, 2, and 3 set up on your administration page?

Comment: Do each of the other applications have their own `Application.cfc` and if so, do they each extend the main one in the root application? Or does each separate `Application.cfc` define the DSNs relative to their needs?

Comment: Yes, they all have there own and extend the main application.cfc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try seeing additional application variables

```
<cfset application.datasource_1 = "DSN2">  (2nd DB)
<cfset application.datasource_2 = "DNS3"> (3rd DB)
```

Comment: Thanks James. But this only gets me this:
Element DSN2 is undefined in APPLICATION. Same issue I had before.

Comment: 1. In your application.cfc file, have you turned on application support? 2.) Do a dump of <cfdump var="#application#"> to see if you have any application variables.

Comment: Also, if you've set the if you're setting the variables in OnApplicationStart (and the app was already running), you may need to restart that application.

Comment: @DavidJacobson, your comment that `Element DSN2 is undefined in APPLICATION` indicates that you are confusing the name of the variable, datasource_1, with its value, DSN2.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to not use any variables at all and simply hard code the datasource names.  In other words, for this:

```
<cfquery name="queryname" datasource="**[What goes here]**"> For second datasource
```

The answer is `"DSN2"`.

In order for these datasources to be usable, they have to be defined on the server and you have to know their names.  If you assign them to some sort of global variable, then you would have to know the name of that variable.  I see no value to using global variables in this situation.

For DSN1, there are pros and cons to using a global variable.  The advantage of a variable is that you don't need a datasource attribute for the queries that use this database.  The disadvantage is that your code becomes a little less consistent if some queries have a datasource attribute and others don't.  That topic is best discussed in person while drinking beer.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the Applicaton.cfc this.datasources struct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please improve this answer by giving a simple example of the `this.datasources struct`.